# Selecting part of an existing div in CSS

Tags: css, facebook, html

im trying to make a facebook like blue bar.
So, i noticed they make a blue bar with width 100%, and make a new div under it which selects half of the div like this(the light blue part is the new div)

[image]

So, then the text or link i put under the new div is alligned just like i want it.
How can i achieve this?
My HTML

```
    <div class="topBar" >
    <div class="bar_frame">
        fuuu
</div>
    </div>
```

And here is my CSS

```
    .topBar {

    background: #3b5998;
    top: 0;
    height: 36px; 
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    position: fixed;

}

.bar_frame{
/* The new div code must go here but i dont know how to do this */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. I'm assuming you just need to center a fixed-width div in its parent element? This is exactly how Facebook does it in your example, and this is how it is done in many cases:

```
.bar_frame{
    width: 981px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mholt/rPKU6/)

Comment: he changed his question to use a class name, you may want to change your answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but thats not working.
And yes, i changed the id attribute to class attribute.

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect the change. Also, @MarshallMathews -- It does actually work. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/mholt/rPKU6/

Comment: oh lol, it did not work because when changing div id to class
i forgot to add a space between div and class, so it was divclass.
Once i cleared that it worked :D
Thanks a lot, i also had to add in the height and set it to the same pixels as the first div to get the exact height too.